# Firebase realtime database with await function in kotlin

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, async-await

I have a trouble using firebase realtime database, I found the reason.
I'm using await function when get the data.
When network is offline, it throws an error and app is closing.
Can you give me the reason?
I have to return this result for use it at the another space that I have to use await function for get the result.
Thanks for reading.
here is my code below.

```
    lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
    database = Firebase.database.reference

    val test: DataSnapshot? = database.child("issuers").child(issuerguid).child("test").get().await()
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a JSON file. You can simply get it by clicking the Export JSON in the overflow menu (⠇) in your [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/database/data). Besides that, if the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. JSON file is not important because ".await()" function make this error. I'm adding error code.

Comment: falling back to disk cache after error: Client is offline 2022-01-25 22:52:31.544 29738-29738/com. E/firebase: Error getting data java.lang.Exception: Client is offline at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl.lambda$get$1$com-google-firebase-database-connection-

Comment: PersistentConnectionImpl(PersistentConnectionImpl.java:441) at com.google.firebase.database.connection.PersistentConnectionImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda4.run(Unknown Source:8) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:458) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at

Comment: java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 2022-01-25 22:52:31.806 29738-29738/com. E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

Comment: I think "await" makes waiting for database, however, it is offline that it makes error. I don't know how to modify my code.

Comment: Then check if it is online or not before fetching data if using await() crash the app when offline

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
fun test(action :(snapShot :DataSnapshot) -> Unit){ 
  database.child("issuers").child(issuerguid).child("test").get()
  .addOnSuccessListener{ snapshot -> 
  action(snapShot)
  }
}

 //usage
 test{
 //use snapshot here
 }
```

Comment: It's not my problem. My program is shut down when I'm using "await()" function in case of offline.

Comment: I know. That's why I am suggesting this approch. You will get what you want to achieve without using await()

Comment: This code is inside of function that I'm return this result in other place. So if I don't use await() then return empty list. Do you mean, your code will return the result?

Comment: suspend fun test(): DataSnapshot? {lateinit var database: DatabaseReference
    database = Firebase.database.reference
    
    val test: DataSnapshot? = database.child("issuers").child(issuerguid).child("test").get().await() return test}

Comment: I am sorry I didn't know you code is inside a function. So I edit my answer take a look. If you want to use await function, the solution would be to check if it isonline before calling the function